# Custom loader like Instagram in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I try to create like this custom rounded corners imageview.I searched out it and I found some examples,but Also I would to create progress bar,I mean progress in this blue border, like instagram.
Can anyone give me a some suggestions, how I can create like this loader?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you want image view loader like in Instagram?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom layout for that. Set the background of the layout (whether constraint, relative or linear) to the drawable you've created and place a progress bar in middle of it.

***Edit: Drawable file ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid

                    android:color="@color/white"/>   <!--Foreground color-->
                <stroke
                    android:color="@color/blue"
                    android:width="1dp"/> <!--stroke color-->
                <corners
                    android:radius="50dp"/>

            </shape>
        </item>


    </selector>
```

Comment: Thanks your attention. I know how to set drawable in progressBar ,but can you share some useful resources about creating like this background(drawable) ? @Mustafa

Comment: @BekaKK The xml codes of the shape in the picture has been added.